# Excel VBA Dropdown-menu

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have some VBA code triggered at cell changes.
One part of the code creates a dropdown in Column C if there are value in Column A on the same row.
There are two things with the dropdown code that I would like to get some help with.

First: If I change the dropdown value for some rows to Yes (there are by default set to No) and then add new value in Column A all dropdown:s changes there values to No. I would like to add some kind of check like that If the value is set to Yes don´t change it back.

Second: Seems like some kind of bug so I will post all my code in case something else might cause it.
Let´s say I have value added in Column A for five rows and I delete them (It doesn´t mather if I delete them one by one or all five at the same time nor the order I delete them). The header in Column C get´s a dropdown after last value in Column A is deleted (Note that Column A also has a header which isn´t deleted.

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop
  On Error GoTo Finalize 'to re-enable the events

  For Each columnAcell In Target.Cells
      columnAcell.Offset(0, 3) = Mid(columnAcell, 2, 3)
      If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 4).ClearContents
      If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 2).Clear
      If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 1).Clear
      If IsEmpty(columnAcell.Value) Then columnAcell.Offset(0, 5).Clear
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
  Dim c As Range, FR As Variant

  Set w1 = Workbooks("Configure Accesspoints.xlsm").Worksheets("AP_Input")
  Set w2 = Workbooks("Configure Accesspoints.xlsm").Worksheets("Data")

  For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
      If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = w2.Range("B" & FR).Value
  Next c

  For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
      If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, 2).Value = w2.Range("D" & FR).Value
  Next c

  Dim myList As String, r As Range

      myList = "Yes,No"

  For Each r In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
      If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
         With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
         End With
         r.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(myList, ",")(1)
      End If
  Next r

Finalize:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, let the VBA remember the old value in the column C. You could set it back.

Dim myList As String, r As Range

```
myList = "Yes,No"
Dim oldYesNo As String
For Each r In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
        If oldYesNo <> vbNullString Then oldYesNo = r.Offset(, 2)
        With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
        End With
        If oldYesNo = vbNullString Then r.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(myList, ",")(1)
        oldYesNo = vbNullString
    End If
Next r
```

The second problem is not a bug. VBA do exactly what you have said it in the line:

```
For Each r In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

If there is only A1 cell filled this works only on A1 cell. You may add a condition;

```
If w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1" Then
```

EDIT: On the second though, remembering the old value is not necessary. Enough is to set values only for new rows.

```
myList = "Yes,No"

If w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address <> "$A$1" Then
    For Each r In w1.Range("A2", w1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If r.Value <> vbNullString Then
            With r.Offset(, 2).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=myList
            End With
            if r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then Split(myList, ",")(1)
        End If
    Next r
End If
```

Maybe there is more elegant solution but this should work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The code you provided changes Header in CollC to "No" directly when I write in CollA.

The dropdown value is also still changed to No when adding more values in CollA.

Comment: Great! It doesn´t change the header in CollC anymore, perfect thanks. But unfortunately it still changes all Yes to No when adding new value.

Comment: I get Syntax error on following row:
if r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then Split(myList, ",")(1). Expeted: =

Comment: If I change the row too, `If r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then Split myList, ","` I doesn´t get any errors but then I don´t have No as standard value. How do I set No as standard aswell?

Comment: Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Does anyone knows how to format this code so that I choose default value? `If r.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then Split myList, ","`